# Как сделать формат даты на русском?

Tags: android, kotlin

Как сделать формат даты, который выводится на экран на русском языке? Например: "26 October" должно выводиться как "26 октября".

```
const val DATE_PATTERN = "d MMMM"
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
fun Date.getDateStringFormat(datePattern: String): String {
    val formatDate = SimpleDateFormat(datePattern)
    return formatDate.format(this)
}
```

Comment: это в большей степени зависит от локали, установленной в настройках телефона

Comment: Переключить аппарат/эмулятор на русский язык. Или использовать конструктор с локалью [`SimpleDateFormat (String pattern, Locale locale)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale)) - но тогда вам придётся самому "договариваться" с пользователем какую именно локаль использовать.